# Add a note about questions that have been asked, and that should not be asked anymore

Tags: discussion

As there is now the possibility of adding a note to a question, should not be there a note for questions that have been asked in the past, and that would be closed, if asked nowadays?

For example, the following note appears in some questions on Stack Overflow:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. More info: FAQ.

The alternative is to close those questions that are now considered off-topic, or that would be closed for any other reason. If there are questions that we think worth being on EL&U, we should consider adding such note.

For a list of possible candidates, you can search them using this search: [is:question answers:20 wiki:1 closed:0](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A20+wiki%3A1+closed%3A0&submit=search).

Answer (score 2):

The SE platform does allow moderators to add such a note (e.g. [What words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-th)), so if you see any questions that you think deserve this post notice, please flag them.

(N.B. The post notice is automatically attached to a lock).

That said, only posts which:

- are of fairly high quality
- have good answers
- are relatively popular (determined either by views or votes)

will be considered for this post notice. If a post does not meet these criteria, the question will simply be closed.